# Amazon DynamoDB modify structure using serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

What is the best way to modify a DynamoDB table structure (no problems on erasing it because of backup)?
I have a table with only HASH KEY.
I have to add a SORT KEY for the table.

When I deploy the stack I receive this error

**Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [DynamoDBTransactionsFinished] in the Resources block of the template**

Some way to solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have references to the DynamoDB table that will fail if you simply delete the DynamoDB table resource from your template, so you may need to add a secondary table that matches the first, repoint all references to the 2nd table, delete the first table, deploy, then modify the template again to re-add the first table (but this time with the additional sort key), repoint the references, delete the 2nd table, redeploy.

Comment: This solved thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I what do. You have references in your template to the DynamoDB table that will fail if you simply delete the DynamoDB table resource from your template, so I would:

1. add a secondary table that matches the first, re-point all references from the 1st table to the 2nd table
2. delete the first table
3. re-deploy your stack
4. modify the template again to re-add the first table, but this time with the additional sort key
5. re-point the references to the new 1st table
6. delete the 2nd table
7. re-deploy the stack